# Adding Class to Element when it's at the Top of the Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, offset, scrolltop

I am trying to add class to elements that hit the top of the screen that have been appended either by clicking a button inside a parent DIV or by entering text within the input form.

It works, but not for the appended elements. And when it does work for the appended elements, it's like the offset of those elements get off each time they get appended and then it applies the class to every appended element after that. It's annoying and I've been stuck on this for at least a week now.

The code I am using to add class when the element hit the top of the screen is this:

```
window.poo = function poo() {
     $("#message").each(function() {


var win = $(".chat-log"),
  nav = $(this),

  pos = nav.offset().top,
  sticky = function() {

    win.scrollTop() > pos ?
       nav.addClass('inactive') :
      nav.removeClass('inactive')
  }

win.scroll(sticky);
});

}

poo();
```

The elements parent is **#message** and the **#message**'s parent is **.chat-log**. I have changed **#message** to **.message** but it still gave me the same result.

And when the user clicks the buttons within the parents, the offset gets worse each time and the class is applied to all elements before they even hit the top of the screen.

Comment: Check here, maybe you'll find : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".chat-log").on("scroll", function() {  
    console.log("I'm scrolling!");

    var win = $(this);  // .chat-log
    win.find(".message").each(function(){

        var nav = $(this);  // each .message found

        //console.log("win: "+win.scrollTop());
        console.log("nav: "+nav.offset().top);

        nav.offset().top < 0 ? nav.addClass('inactive') : nav.removeClass('inactive')
    });
});
```

Comment: I did it but it's not applying for dynamic elements. :(

Comment: And like this... ??

Comment: I tried using .on("scroll") many times and it doesn't work at all. Could there be anything that is interfering with the code? It's like 3,000+ lines of code lol so it's going to be tough to single it out.

Comment: I've looked at the view-source more colsely... look at my new edit. I'm not sure it works, but it's getting closer. I added a console.log .. Just to be sure we're on the right scroll event... As a begining. ;)

Comment: Yes! It's getting closer. I updated the site. It's applying the class before the elements reach the top of the screen. Each appended element gets a class way before then.

Comment: Yes... I see your `.bitch` class. (lol!) Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: lmaooo oops. I got mad so thats just me getting putting things like that. And it's whatever you want to name it.

Comment: The thing is that you have to attach the event on an existing element... So in this case, to reach the dynamically appended, I used .find() from this existing element... And that's it.

Comment: Ok I see... Element gets the bitch class too soon...Hold on

Comment: So should I detach them from the other element or just use find()? I am using it but the class still gets added before they reach the top. Hmmm. At least it's adding it.

Comment: I added to new console logs... so you will see what is compared in your condition

Comment: I added the new code. Sorry for asking dumb questions, but what does a console log do? I'm learning and you're helping a lot. Does it tell you the problems with a certain code?

Comment: Hit F-12 on your keyboard. console.log prints message in the console. It's helpfull to debug.

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhhh. It works now. You're amazing. Now I won't have to use the `bitch` class. Lmaoooo.

Comment: Cool... You can play with the value to compare... Something like `nav.offset().top < 50` will show a couple black lines. Please, accept the answer (green check mark). ;)

Comment: If I ever need help again, I'm coming to you. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to attach a function to every `.chat-log` div, so it executes on scroll. The problem is when this executes, there is only one such div, so only it will change its class when passing the top.

You have to change the function so the `for each` is inside the function that is executed on every scroll. You could for example attach it to the window, and inside it you search to which divs the style should be applied.